# How to select first occurrence of some class

Tags: html, css

Supoose you have something like

```
<div class="base">
    <div>
        ...
            <div class="ok">
                <div>
                    ...
                        <div class="ok"></div>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
       ...
   </div>    
</div>
```

Here I've shown just a couple of DIVs, but it can be any level deep (note the ...)

So the question is: How can I style the first element with the class `ok`without knowing how deep it is nested ?

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vkt8mLzo/2/) in which you can see I style all the DIVs with the class `ok`

Comment: are your divs all nested, or there are some siblings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no selector for that, but there is override workaround:
you can apply some css to all `.ok` and then reset on all nested `.ok`

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ok {
  background-color: gray;
}
.ok .ok{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  ...
  <div class="ok">
    ...
    <div class="ok">
      ...
      <div class="ok">
        ...
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes that, with the exception of "the first one", all elements that are members of that class will be descendants of "the first one". That is true of the example in the question, but it isn't clear if that is the case universally.

Comment: true, we shall ask

Comment: In my specific case I need to style the first `ok` not the ones nested deeper, meaning that this works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS provides no functionality to select an element based on anything that appears in the document after its start tag. Not descendants, not later siblings, and not later siblings of its ancestors.

You'd need to use JavaScript for this. Something along the lines of:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector(".ok").classList.add("ok-first");
});
```